# Multi part RegEx in IIS 7 URL Rewriter for outbound links

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have been trying to get the [IIS URL Rewrite engine](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/) to work for a specific case of outbound URLs. I am trying to lowercase all URLs except for those that match these criteria:

- An outbound link with a hash tag: **page.aspx#q=MixedCaseParameter**
- An already rewritten outbound friendly URL with a mixed case product id and product description: **/shopping/product/A12345/Mixed-Case-Product-Description**
- An outbound link with javascript: in the HREF instead of a URL: **javascript:__doPostBack('control','action')**

I can do parts of it, but not all of it in one expression, but I can't get all three. Here is what I have right now:

```
([A-Z]+)((?:(?!app\.aspx#q).)|(?:^(?!javascript:).))
```

And the settings in the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <!-- other rules excluded for clarity -->
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">

    <rule name="Outbound lowercase" preCondition="IsHTML" enabled="true">
      <match filterByTags="A" pattern="([A-Z]+)((?:(?!app\.aspx#q).)|(?:^(?!javascript:).))" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{ToLower:{R:0}}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Example friendly outbound rewrite rule -->
    <rule name="Rewrite Product Outbound" preCondition="IsHTML" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match filterByTags="A" pattern="product\.aspx\?cat=catalogname&amp;amp;pid=([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)&amp;amp;pdisplayname=([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/shopping/product/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
    </rule>

    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsHTML" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
    <!-- Shopping Outbound Rules End -->
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that will match the three types of outbound urls you don't want to lowercase :

```
.*?page\.aspx#q|.*?/shopping/product|^javascript:
```

Test :

```
page.aspx#q=MixedCaseParameter                              => Matched
/shopping/product/A12345/Mixed-Case-Product-Description     => Matched
javascript:__doPostBack('control','action')                 => Matched 
http://google.com                                           => NOT Matched
```